# Python/Pandas: creating new dataframe, gets error "unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer"

Tags: python, dataframe, series

I am trying to compare two dataframes and return different result sets based on whether a value from one dataframe is present in the other.

Here is my sample code:

```
pmdf = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'Journal' : ['US Drug standards.','Acta veterinariae.','Bulletin of big toe science.','The UK journal of dermatology.','Journal of Hypothetical Journals'],
        'ISSN': ['0096-0225', '0567-8315','0007-4977','0007-0963','8675-309J'],
        }
        )

pmdf = pmdf[['Journal'] + pmdf.columns[:-1].tolist()]

jcrdf = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'Full Journal Title': ['Drug standards.','Acta veterinaria.','Bulletin of marine science.','The British journal of dermatology.'],
        'Abbreviated Title': ['DStan','Avet','Marsci','BritSkin'],
        'Total Cites': ['223','444','324','166'],
        'ISSN': ['0096-0225','0567-8315','0007-4977','0007-0963'],   
        'All_ISSNs': ['0096-0225,0096-0225','0567-8315,1820-7448,0567-8315','0007-4977,0007-4977','0007-0963,0007-0963,0366-077X,1365-2133']                        
         })
jcrdf = jcrdf.set_index('Full Journal Title')

pmdf_issn = pmdf['ISSN'].values.tolist()
```

This line gets me the rows from dataframe jcrdf that contain the issn from dataframe pmdf

```
pmjcrmatch = jcrdf[jcrdf['All_ISSNs'].str.contains('|'.join(pmdf_issn))]
```

I wanted the following line to create a new dataframe of values from pmdf where the ISSN is not in jcfdf so I negated the previous statement and chose the first dataframe.

```
pmjcrnomatch = pmdf[~jcrdf['All_ISSNs'].str.contains('|'.join(pmdf_issn))]
```

I get an error: "Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match"

I don't find a lot about this specific error, at least nothing that is helping me toward a solution.

Is "str.contains" not the best way of sorting items that are and aren't in the second dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply the boolean index of one dataframe to another. This is only possible if the length of both dataframes match. In your case you should use `isin`.

```
# get all rows from jcrdf where `ALL_ISSNs` contains any of the `ISSN` in `pmdf`.
pmjcrmatch = jcrdf[jcrdf.All_ISSNs.str.contains('|'.join(pmdf.ISSN))]
# assign all remaining rows from `jcrdf` to a new dataframe.
pmjcrnomatch = jcrdf[~jcrdf.ISSN.isin(pmjcrmatch.ISSN)]
```

**EDIT** 
Let's try another approach:

First i'd create a lookup for all you ISSNs and then create the diff by isolating the matches:

```
import pandas as pd

pmdf = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'Journal' : ['US Drug standards.','Acta veterinariae.','Bulletin of big toe science.','The UK journal of dermatology.','Journal of Hypothetical Journals'],
        'ISSN': ['0096-0225', '0567-8315','0007-4977','0007-0963','8675-309J'],
        }
        )

pmdf = pmdf[['Journal'] + pmdf.columns[:-1].tolist()]

jcrdf = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'Full Journal Title': ['Drug standards.','Acta veterinaria.','Bulletin of marine science.','The British journal of dermatology.'],
        'Abbreviated Title': ['DStan','Avet','Marsci','BritSkin'],
        'Total Cites': ['223','444','324','166'],
        'ISSN': ['0096-0225','0567-8315','0007-4977','0007-0963'],
        'All_ISSNs': ['0096-0225,0096-0225','0567-8315,1820-7448,0567-8315','0007-4977,0007-4977','0007-0963,0007-0963,0366-077X,1365-2133']
         })
jcrdf = jcrdf.set_index('Full Journal Title')

# create lookup from all issns to avoid expansice string matching
jcrdf_lookup = pd.DataFrame(jcrdf['All_ISSNs'].str.split(',').tolist(),
                            index=jcrdf.ISSN).stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0)

# compare extracted ISSNs from ALL_ISSNs with pmdf.ISSN
matches = jcrdf_lookup[jcrdf_lookup[0].isin(pmdf.ISSN)]
jcrdfmatch = jcrdf[jcrdf.ISSN.isin(matches.ISSN)]
jcrdfnomatch = pmdf[~pmdf.ISSN.isin(matches[0])]
```

Comment: Actually, I thought "isin" only works for a complete match. I am searching in the "ALL_ISSNs" column where each row has multiple ISSNs, so I used "str.contains" for a partial match.

Comment: That's correct. I just changed the way you are creating the `pmjcrnomatch`.

Comment: This line: `pmjcrnomatch = pmdf[~pmdf.ISSN.isin(pmjcrmatch.ISSN)]` will result in some journals in both result sets. This code works in my sample data but in my live data I am seeing the same journal in both pmjcrmatch and pmjcrnomatch. I think I need to use 'str.contains' so I can return rows from pmdf if the pmdf.ISSN value is not present in jcrdf.ALL_ISSNs. Thanks again

Comment: I updated the answer to only use `jcrdf` as a reference. Now it should work.

Comment: I have tried that approach but the problem with that is, it can't pull rows from jcrdf if pmdf.issn isn't in it.

I need to know the name and ISSN of journals that fail to match, so those data points won't be in the second dataframe. The reference has to be from pmdf. 

Is this a time for a lambda expression, maybe?

Comment: Ok I guess now I understand what you're trying to do. I updated the answer again.

Comment: My problem is my live data is hard to add here. I think I need to change the value of jcrdf.ISSN to pmdf.ISSN where pmdf.ISSN is in jcrdf.ALL_ISSNs. That way I can do a merge on the ISSN column name which is common to both dataframes.